# How to get authenticated by Telegram bot in Group chats?

Tags: authentication, telegram-bot

Please kindly someone explain me how can the Telegram bot could understand who is sending the command in group chats and respond it with the the unique answer which is just for that user.
Surely in this case security issues should be considered and a user must not send command as another user. 
I guess I can use username to send along with command. 
Any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) Object contains two objects apart from other objects:

1. [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat), `message['chat']` which represents the Chat from which the message is coming. In your case the group.
2. [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user), `message['from']` which represents the user that sent the message/command.

So it's easy to differentiate which user sent the message. And in case of Private chats, both the Chat object and the User Object are same.